# Error creating IBM Containers 404: Resource not found

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

Good night , does anyone can help me , I'm trying to create an IBM Containers for my app , but is experiencing an error in the end.

404: Resource not found

Comment: Have you looked in your server logs?

Comment: I am new to bluemix , where the logs is ?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Bluemix, but I found some links that may be helpful: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/10/29/accessing-application-logs-bluemix/ and http://bluemixtips.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-track-error-log-on-bluemix.html

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error when running cf ic login you have to check the cf api https://api.[region].bluemix.net URL you are using, where [region] could have ng or eu-gb value according to the region used (us or UK).
If the error you got is requesting a page from your service running on the container, it is depending from your container, so first check the ip used, then the path requested

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the logs of your container in the Bluemix Dashboard.

First of all, in the Dashboard you see a green/yellow/red indicator on your container tile/icon indicating if your container is running or has an issue.

When you click on the container tile, in the left menu you will see a Monitoring and Logs item. In the logging tab make sure the time "window" is large enough, there is this pull down in the upper right part which by default displays only the last 30 minutes of the logs.

You can also get to the logs from the command line with "cf ic logs "

If the logs don't help you, can you be more specific in what you attempt to do?